# Deeplake output of all stored files

Tags: python, langchain, vector-database, deeplake

With the
 `docs = (db.similarity_search(query='some query here'))`
method to output single or multiple documents of the deeplake vectorstore. Is there a method to output all documents?
Because my documents are structured like this:

```
page_content='256 128 256zM208 160c-8,836 0-16-...
384C234.5 384 256 362.5 256 336C256 309.5 234.5 288 208' 
metadata={'source':'chatbot/app/solid.min.js','file_name':'solid.min.js'}
```

And I would genre all documents whose metadata.file_name corresponds to a particular file. Unfortunately I can't find any recordings for this and that's why I'm asking here for experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can query and apply filter on your metadata

```
       def query_datalake(db, query, subject):

        filter={"metadata": {"source": f"output\\{subject}.txt"}}  
        #Distance function L2 for Euclidean, L1 for Nuclear, Max l-infinity distance, cos for cosine similarity, dot for dot product
        docs = db.similarity_search(query, filter=filter, distance_metric="cos", k=10)

        return docs
```

Comment: that's great, but does not show all docs to the source. 
As example: I have chunked the File 'test.txt' to 10 Chunks and stored them I the db, your function outputs only a few of them, but I need all.

Comment: modified the answer to bring all documents, you can modify "k" based on your requirement